# Turning on GRASS plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation

I downloaded and installed Quantum GIS 1.5.0 with GRASS using the OSGeo4W installer on my Windows XP machine.  Unfortunately, when I go to Plugins>Manage Plugins I cannot find the GRASS plugin.  When I browse to OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\plugins I can see grassplugin.dll, grassrasterprovider.dll and grassprovider.dll.

How do I make QGIS recognize the GRASS install?

Comment: New and related development: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/319333/5256

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just installed QGIS 1.5.0 two days ago. The GRASS plugin shows up in my Plugin Manager and under the Plugin Menu. I used the Standalone Installer though, rather than the OSGeo4W Installer. You might want to try that route. (http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Download)

You also have to set up a GRASS Database through the  "Plugins > Grass > New Mapset" menu in order to get the other GRASS Plugin Menu items to become active.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See also the draft "QGIS GRASS Cookbook" which is available here: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/QGIS_GRASS_Cookbook

In the long run it should go into the QGIS user manual as well.