# Exposing GRASS GIS add-on in QGIS Processing framework?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, add-ons

Having QGIS and GRASS GIS 7 installed, how can I expose a GRASS GIS add-on, which has been installed using `g.extension`, in QGIS' Processing framework?

Answer (score 6):

QGIS core developer Nyal Dawson explained [a best-practice](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2019-February/056155.html) approach in this [e-mail thread](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2019-February/056140.html).

### Overview

1. Subclass QGIS' class [`Grass7AlgorithmProvider`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/1d8bd004a619cb001cfc469fd42a6f71ecb93888/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7AlgorithmProvider.py#L45)
2. Set the value of [`descriptionFolder`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/1d8bd004a619cb001cfc469fd42a6f71ecb93888/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7AlgorithmProvider.py#L49) to the path of the add-on in question
3. Override the methods for logo, descriptions, name etc.

An example of it, implemented by [Panagiotis Mavrogiorgos](https://github.com/pmav99) is https://gitlab.com/natcapes/natcapes_qgis, which literally exposes the https://gitlab.com/natcapes/r.estimap.recreation GRASS GIS add-on under Processing.

Finally, it would be nice to have an update for https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21322 -- essentially, an update of the "documentation" file https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/grass7.txt.

### Related Screenshots

- Processing Toolbox and the normal GRASS GIS provider: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oyeo.png
- QGIS Plugin in the 'natcapes_qgis' repository: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8csL.png
- Install (the above mentioned QGIS) Plugin from ZIP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr31u.png
- Plugin installed, provider activated: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2iG5.png
- The interface to `r.estimap.recreation`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHpQF.png